# How do we programmatically create Role, Permissions in Liferay for a User and Site Template?

Tags: liferay

As a programmer, I would like to create Role and Permissions in Liferay and assign it to a User and a Site template or site without the intervention of Liferay Admin.

Please help me with the code if anybody has already done it. I am using Liferay 6.1

Answer (score 1):

Liferay Provides set of api for doing create user , roles etc . You could go through below api which will create user and role also assign respected association between user, site and roles

https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserLocalServiceUtil.html

https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/RoleLocalServiceUtil.html

Thanks